# how to hook function in smartpy FA2

Tags: smartpy, transfer, fa2

when calling transfer method, how to call hook method on received smart contract.
I'm using fa2 in smartpy

Comment: What is your scenario, are you calling from another contract or from an app?

Comment: when contract received the token, I want to recording in contract. 'when' 'who' 'how much' . so I need hook function like ERC777TokensRecipient And The tokensReceived Hook on ethereum

Comment: Receiver hooks in FA2 are optional. If the particular implementation of the FA2 supports receiver hooks, you receiver contract may implement `tokens_received` entry point.
See [FA2 token owner hook](https://gitlab.com/tzip/tzip/-/blob/master/proposals/tzip-12/tzip-12.md#token-owner-hook-permission-behavior) and some [example implementation](https://github.com/tqtezos/smart-contracts/tree/master/collectibles).
However due to inter-contract calls gas costs, most of the existing FA2 implementations choose not to support sender/receiver hooks